# RTP packet identification

Tags: sockets, rtsp, rtp, ip-camera

I'm working on implementation of RTSP/RTP client and thinking on how to deal with client sockets per RTP session. Is it possible to reuse same socket pairs for different RTP sources? Say I have many IP cameras and I wish to receive media data from them to the single set of RTP client ports (two ports for video (data and control ports) and two ports for audio). In other words I don't want to have as many client sockets sets as amount of IP cameras. If I would receive many data streams into one socket I wonder how to differentiate which RTP packet belongs to which camera?

Answer (score 1):

That's what the SSRC field of the RTP header is for. From RFC3550:

> Synchronization source (SSRC): The source of a stream of RTP
>         packets, identified by a 32-bit numeric SSRC identifier carried in
>         the RTP header so as not to be dependent upon the network address.
>         All packets from a synchronization source form part of the same
>         timing and sequence number space, so a receiver groups packets by
>         synchronization source for playback.  Examples of synchronization
>         sources include the sender of a stream of packets derived from a
>         signal source such as a microphone or a camera, or an RTP mixer
>         (see below).  A synchronization source may change its data format,
>         e.g., audio encoding, over time.  The SSRC identifier is a
>         randomly chosen value meant to be globally unique within a
>         particular RTP session (see Section 8).  A participant need not
>         use the same SSRC identifier for all the RTP sessions in a
>         multimedia session; the binding of the SSRC identifiers is
>         provided through RTCP (see Section 6.5.1).  If a participant
>         generates multiple streams in one RTP session, for example from
>         separate video cameras, each MUST be identified as a different
>         SSRC.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only bind the sockets but don't connect them it is possible. You then have to call recvfrom which provides you with the sender of the packet.